# Applescript Syntax error when using excel "open workbook" command

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

[Here is a screenshot of the relevant Excel Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC0cP.png)

[Here is a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFNMd.png)

Here is my code:

```
on saveExcelAsPDF(documentPath, PDFPath)
    set tFile to (POSIX path of documentPath) as POSIX file

    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        set isRun to running
        set wkbk1 to open workbook workbook file name tFile
        alias PDFPath
        save workbook as wkbk1 filename PDFPath file format PDF file format with overwrite
        close wkbk1 saving no
        if not isRun then quit
    end tell
end saveExcelAsPDF
```

When I try to compile I get an error alert which says "Syntax Error;  Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier" and the second "workbook" word is highlighted on line 6.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  When I used the line 'tell application "Microsoft Excel"', it was referring to the Windows version of Excel (running via parallels desktop), instead of Excel for Mac.  I replaced that line with 'tell application "/Applications/Microsoft Excel.app"' and it compiles perfectly now.